# "ng serve --prod" getting some errors

Tags: angular, command-line-interface

ERROR in Internal error: unknown identifier 300

ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory' in 'C:\Users...\ng-webapp
\src'
 @ ./src/main.ts 3:0-74
 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/main.ts

**Thank you for you help  !**

I found some answer from google bu it doesn't work for me ,such as updated "angular/cli" version or installed enhanced-resolve@3.3.0 ,but still the same error.

This is some content in package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "^4.0.0",
  "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
  "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
  "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
  "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
  "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
  "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
  "animate.css": "3.5.2",
  "chart.js": "^2.1.3",
  "core-js": "^2.4.1",
  "echarts": "^3.6.2",
  "enhanced-resolve": "^3.3.0",
  "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
  "fullcalendar": "3.3.1",
  "jquery": "3.2.1",
  "jquery-slimscroll": "1.3.8",
  "ng-prism": "^2.3.4",
  "ngx-bootstrap": "^1.7.1",
  "ngx-echarts": "^1.2.1",
  "primeng": "^4.0.0",
  "prismjs": "^1.6.0",
  "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
  "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@angular/cli": "1.0.4",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
  "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
  "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
  "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
  "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
  "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
  "karma": "~1.4.1",
  "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
  "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
  "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
  "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
  "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
  "protractor": "~5.1.0",
  "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
  "tslint": "~4.5.0",
  "typescript": "~2.2.0"
}
```

Comment: Using 'ng serve',it has no issue！what happened with "--prod"?

Comment: well i also get this error in newer versions of angular/cli, the problem is that there are some particular component which does not included in any angular module, delete them or use them in any module.

Comment: To what version did you update the cli?

Comment: aot is the issue here check your app for aot compatiblity

Comment: @Touqeer Shafi  Thank you for your answer，it's solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can build Your by this command:

`ng build --prod --aot=false -bh /<base-href> -d /<dir>`

replace `<base-href>` by Your own base href and `<dir>` by Your project folder name

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46277746/ng-serve-prod-getting-some-errors?noredirect=1#comment79519140_46277746) that in newer angular/cli version if you have not declared any component which is exists in your application directory structure it will throw this type of error:

```
ERROR in Internal error: unknown identifier 300

ERROR in ./src/main.ts Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory' in 'C:\Users...\ng-webapp \src' @ ./src/main.ts 3:0-74 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/main.ts
```